# Is there some medicine that can safely and reliably cause mild nausea?

Tags: nausea

Is there some medicine that can safely and reliably cause mild nausea? Like a pill that would make the one who takes it nauseous for an hour and that's it. And by *safely* I mean that there would not be any other adverse effects except the nausea itself.

Comment: Since you admitted in comments that your reason for asking is appetite control, I'm voting to close as a request for medical advice.

Comment: Nothing that induces vomiting is really safe. As a means for appetite control this is *not even wrong* but absurd. If you ask another question about appetite control alone, please do so. But first visit a doctor about these underlying issues and then read [how to ask](https://health.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @LangLangC the question is not about inducing vomiting - it is about causing mild nausea (without actual vomiting).

Comment: @Enivid Whether you end up vomiting or not the end result is the same: you're using nausea to reduce caloric intake. I think mental health professionals would label that bulimia. In any case, you're asking for personal medical advice and that's strictly off topic here.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you have a test to avoid, in which case you can probably just say you are feeling nauseous. If you really want to make yourself (or someone else) feel nauseous, depending on your sensitivity to motion sickness, you can put wamr (or cold) water in the ear canal. This is basically what a [caloric test](https://medlineplus.gov/ency/article/003429.htm) of balance is.

Comment: Alternative solution: *Throwing up*. Beginners Level: 100ml milk mixed with 100ml sparkling water. If that doesn’t make you sick, advance to Immediate Level: add 100ml orange juice. Advanced Level: add 2mg toothpaste. Expert Level: Add 2 raw eggs. Zombie Level: Add 2 year old, rotten flesh. Ultimate Level: Stick a laryngeal Tube in your mouth while conscious and remove it as soon as the urge to vomit starts.

Comment: @StrongBad, no, it is not to avoid a test. I am interested in it from the appetite control point of view.

Comment: @Enivid The word for that is bulimia. You might want to look it up and see what wonderful things it will do for your health.

Comment: @CareyGregory I know what bulimia is. The question is not about causing vomiting to get rid of the consumed food. It is about causing mild nausea.